# request fail with axios but succed with fetch

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get data from my API with axios (with this error 400)

```
 axios.post('http://localhost:8086/api/login', 
   '{"username" : "user", "password" : "pwd"}', header)
 .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
 })
 .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
 });
```

with this code, it's working but I don't want to use fetch (here retrun 200)

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8086/api/login';
let data = '{"password":  "pwd", "username": "user"}'
let fetchData = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
    headers: new Headers()
}
fetch(url, fetchData)
  .then(response => {
       console.log(response.body)
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.log("error")
       console.log(error)
    });
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: What happens if you post a json object instead of a string to Axios?

Comment: The second parameter in `axios.post` method should be an `object` not a `string`

Answer (score 1):

From [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) docs"

> axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

Where the `config` is a object, see *Request Config* section.
So to make it working you should change the second parameter of your `axios.post` method to object, instead of

`'{"username" : "user", "password" : "pwd"}'`

should be

`{"username" : "user", "password" : "pwd"}`

**UPDATE**

You should use it as the follow:

```
axios.post('localhost:8086/api/login', {"username" : "user", "password" : "pwd"}, header)
```

Hope it make sense.

Comment: with this  axios.post('http://localhost:8086/api/login',
            [{"username" : "user", "password" : "pwd"}]) i get a 405

Comment: @tetar why do you use an `array` as a second parameter? You should use an `object` instead!